# How to upgrade from Oracle Express to Standard using the export / import dump method?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to upgrade the Oracle DB from Express 11g to Standard 11g.
I know how to export and import between two machines that run Express, but when i need to import the dump on Standard, i have no idea where to put the .dmp file or how to import it.

For the export i am using this command:

```
expdp Test/Pc DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=EX2.dmp
```

Which creates a dump file in this location:

```
 C:\oracle\app\oracle\admin\xe\dpdump\EX2.dmp
```

Now, if i wanted to just import the dump into an Express edition, i would run this command:

```
impdp Test/Pc DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=EX2.dmp TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=REPLACE
```

But that directory is not created when you install the Standard edition.

So my question is, what is the equivalent of that directory, when installing Standard edition? Also, is this the right way to upgrade from XE to STD? The upgrade using the assistant does not work for other unknown reasons.

Comment: Can't you just create a new `DIRECTORY` object pointing to that directory? Remember you need to grant permissions on it to the DB user doing the import too.

Comment: `CREATE DIRECTORY dmpdir AS 'C:\oracle\app\oracle\admin\xe\dpdump\';`  Something like that? And then when importing - `DIRECTORY=dmpdir` ?

Comment: Yep; and `GRANT read, write ON DIRECTORY dmpdir TO test`.

Comment: Alright i think i know how to answer this... just need some time to figure it all out 100%