# How to backup Oracle Express and restore it to standard version

Tags: oracle

Is there any way backup database in Oracle express and restore this database into Oracle standard edition.

In my case, I have a database in Oracle express version 11.1.2. I can backup this database to dmp file and restore to other express version 11.1.2. But I need restore it to Oracle 11.2 standard edition.

Comment: You're doing an export and import, not a backup and restore. Have you tried to import your express-generated file into a standard-edition DB?

Comment: Thank Alex Poole! I tried impdp and expdp and success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to upgrade from Oracle Express to Standard using the export / import dump method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21309972/how-to-upgrade-from-oracle-express-to-standard-using-the-export-import-dump-me) 
Is this the answer you're looking for? Just export with expdp from XE, and import with impdp? 
I see no reason to "backup"  and "restore". You want to migrate the data. that should be possible. Have you tried?

Comment: Thanks Non Plus Ultra. I tried as in your link and it worded. In the first time, i get error "incompatible version number 3.1 in dump file" and i solved this by this link: http://sunkupuli.com/2013/02/26/ora-39142-incompatible-version-number-3-1-in-dump-file/